# How to create a Struts project in JDeveloper

Tags: jdeveloper

I am using **JDeveloper 10.1**. I want to create a project using **Struts** framework which will include Java, jsp and js etc. Will really appreciate if someone can tell me the procedure for creating a Struts framework in JDeveloper.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Creating **Struts** based project in not a big deal. You can create a simple web based project and then configure the struts action based xml to it. May be following links would help you.

1. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/strutshowto-087240.html
2. http://blog.csdn.net/bmjwin/article/details/4307239

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to go with Struts? In newer versions of JDeveloper Struts has been replaced with the more modern and capable Java EE standard JSF.
I would recommend you'll pick up that technology.

If you really want Struts see the old tutorials from the old days here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/index-095995.html